# GCC: make "#pragma message "humpty dumpty" stand out more

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor, pragma

In my source file I have a couple notes that I want clearly printed on my screen. For this I use:

```
    #pragma message "****************************"
    #pragma message "*"
    #pragma message "* Setting fuses for ATtiny45"
    #pragma message "*"
    #pragma message "****************************"
```

But is there a smarter/shorter way to make a message stand out from the other compiler message,  one that doesn't require 5 lines of code repeated for every message?

Comment: `#pragma message "OMFG LOOK AT THIS MESSAGE! LOOK AT ITTTTTTTTT!!!! >>> Setting fuses for ATtiny45"`. Seriously, any answer you get will be an opinion.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
#define MSG(X) "\n****************************\n*\n* " X "\n*\n****************************\n"
#pragma message MSG("Setting fuses for ATtiny45")
```